# Segfault accessing or setting struct member

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

It's been a while since I worked with pointers or C in general. I'm working on a project (malloc implementation related) for school but can't make progress past the initial phase because I'm having segfault issues, and I know where it is going wrong after debugging but I'm not sure why. Here is the code:

```html
typedef struct blah bloo;

struct blah {
    int c;
    bloo *next;
};

int init_func() {
    bloo *foo = (bloo*) sbrk(0);
    sbrk(10000);
    foo->c = 0; //Where the segfault occurs
    ....
    return 9001;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions towards the correct path. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The brk and sbrk functions are historical curiosities left over from earlier days before the advent of virtual memory management.  That's what the man page says. Try `malloc`.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm trying to implement a version of malloc and part of the requirements is to use sbrk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including sys/types.h fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With `sbrk(0)` you allocate 0 bytes of memory. I think that what you really want is

```
 bloo *foo = (bloo*) sbrk(sizeof(struct blah));
```

Also note that the man page for sbrk says:

```
Avoid using brk() and sbrk(): the malloc(3) memory allocation 
package is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.
```

Expect your program/implementation to behave differently on different architectures.

Comment: I've tried your code and I am still getting a segfault.

Comment: Try commenting out your second call to `sbrk` as well. where you call it with 10000

Comment: You should also add some error detection on the call to sbrk - see the man page for details on return values from that function

Comment: I have just tried to comment out the second call to sbrk. It still segfaults. I believe sbrk is returning the correct previous program break. As in, if I print the program break before and after sbrk, it seems to have incremented.

Comment: Then the return value is probable `(void*)-1`, indicating an error in allocating memory. Check man page for details on further reading.

Comment: If it were correct, you'd hardly get a segfault, would you?